# Calculating percentage for each value in multiply columns. based on maximum value in each column using R

Tags: r, loops, max, percentage

I am trying to form a loop where it takes the maximum value from each column, then use it to calculate the percentage for the other values within each column. Someone asked a similar question in the past before, however the solution given was calculating the percentages the opposite way round to what I need.

**My df**:

| a | b | c | d |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1115.68 | 67.52 | 151.13 | 183.32 |  |
| 1083.16 | 53.75 | 136.70 | 202.56 |  |
| 1076.69 | 56.07 | 157.77 | 196.43 |  |

**Desire output**:

| a | b | c | d |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 100.00 | 95.79 | 90.50 |  |
| 97.09 | 79.61 | 86.65 | 100.00 |  |
| 96.51 | 83.05 | 100.00 | 96.97 |  |

**Current output**, I am getting the percentages in the opposite way round:

| a | b | c | d |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 6.05 | 13.55 | 16.43 |  |
| 100.00 | 4.96 | 12.62 | 18.70 |  |
| 100.00 | 5.21 | 14.65 | 18.24 |  |

The code I was using is this:

```
output <- df
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  highvalue <- max(df[i, 1:4])
  for (j in 1:4) {
    output[i, j] <- df[i, j] * 100/highvalue
  }
}
output
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find maximum in row, not in column. Loop version:

```
output <- df
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  highvalue <- max(df[, i])
  output[, i] <- output[, i] / highvalue * 100
}
```

But You can use good version of code:

```
library(dplyr)
output <- df / df %>% lapply(max) * 100
```